# Models Field in Django for React3Fiber customized environment

Tags: django-models

I would like to design a system with Django where a customer get a personnalized react3fiber environment with his own picture. I don’t feel good with my models, as I can’t see the way I will link let’s say 10 product A with ten customers and each time different pictures (UploadedFile in this case)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`UploadedFile` is a many-to-many relation between `User` and `Product` according to the ER diagram you have shared in your question. That is, if there are many users to share the same product picture, then you will have multiple `UploadedFile` records with the same `user`, but different `product` field values for the same `file_url`. If there are multiple products to share the same user picture, then you will have multiple `UploadedFile` records with the same `product` value but different `user` values while `file_url` would be the same.

**Your scenario**: You want to have 10 products with 10 customers and each time with different pictures. But that is also solvable, nothing stops you, at least according to the ER diagram from creating 10 `UploadFile` records for 10 customers each (that's 10 * 10 = 100 `UploadFile` records) with varying `file_url` values.

Of course, things also depend on:

- the actual database schema
- triggers/constraints
- model limitations not present in the ER diagram
- source-code of Django